# Jenkinsfile Credentials as parameter is not read

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I am trying to use the credentials parameter for a git clone.  But i am getting the error that the variables are not found

Param definition

```
  credentials (credentialType: 'Username with password', defaultValue: 'fcb2d7c3-4b35-4ef2-bdf0-24fc4ff1137c', description: 'Git credential', name: 'git_credential', required: true)
```

Usage in stage

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: params.git_credential, passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME')]) {
sh 'git reset --hard; git clone https://${DOCKER_USERNAME}:${DOCKER_PASSWORD}@repo_url/scm/${params.repository}.git --branch master'
```

> Error: Wrong variable used

Comment: Params.repository probably unknown.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  parameters {
    // credentials : defaultValue is Credentials ID
    credentials(name: 'git_credential', description: 'Git credential', defaultValue: 'fcb2d7c3-4b35-4ef2-bdf0-24fc4ff1137c', credentialType: "Username with password", required: true )
  }
  stages {
    stage('Print') {
      steps {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(
          credentialsId: '${git_credential}',
          usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME',
          passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD',
        )]) {
          sh """
            echo id:${DOCKER_USERNAME} pw:${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```